# Scanner.next() Consuming line before in CSV (JAVA)

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to output a CSV file into an array, well right now I just want to print out specific numbers from the CSV file I'm reading from.

```
1000,Mycat,Tucson,Arizona,85725
1013,Demizz,Tucson,Arizona,85710
I0053,1/11/2014,7298.88
P534,485.67,Nulla ac enim. In tempor turpis nec euismod scelerisque quam        turpis adipiscing lorem vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem. Duis aliquam convallis nunc.
```

I only want to output the 1000 and 1013.

```
inFile.useDelimiter(",");
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    strContains = inFile.next();
    if (strContains.contains(" 1013")) {
        System.out.println(strContains);
    }
}
```

In the example I posted I used .contains to find the only line with "  1013" in it, however the output gives me

```
85725
1013
```

Can anyone explain why the 85725 is being tagged with the 1013 when I try to print and how I can fix it? I don't know how to fire a blank without skipping the line so that Scanner will function properly.

Comment: *"85725  1013"* is obviously one single token, since the scanner uses only the "," as the delimiter and not `\n` (+`\r`).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tom already mentioned in the comments your problem is that your `StringTokenizer`  or whatever class you are using does not recognize  the linefeed as a delimiter. Therefore `85725\n1012` gets recognized as one token. The easiest way to fix this would be adding colons at the end of each line. Another possibility would be, to add the linefeed character to your set of delimiters. Using the `StringTokenizer` class you could use this:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fileContentAsString, ",\n");
```

but you have to check if your string still contains special character like `\n` and `\r`. For example if you use a `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` method to read in the file those characters get lost.
Try something like this:

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
try {
    //Read in the file character by character to get linefeeds
    Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
    String fileContent = "";
    int character;
    while ((character = reader.read()) != -1)
        fileContent += (char) character;

    //Create tokenizer with comma and linefeed as delimiter
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fileContent, ",\n");

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if (token.contains("1013"))
            System.out.println(token);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This prints out:

```
1013
```

using your example file.